# Google meet for kids? What software for a child to video chat

Tags: video-conferencing

I am looking for software for the child to be able to contact me through video chat. Can I set in google meet so that the child can only call me? I would like such a safe communicator. Thanks for the answers :)
EDIT, for Android tablet. Control person is me.

Comment: For which system(s)? WIndows PC, Android phone? How should you be able to control the available contact(s)? Stationary, remotely?